# how should i print the value in success on ajax in my modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this javascript function and it is called when user clicked a button which triggers to open a modal:

```
function view(idjob, name)
{
    document.getElementById('jtitle').innerHTML = name;
    $.ajax({ url: 'passJobID.php',
        data: {'vals' : idjob},
        type: 'post',
        dataType:'html',
        success: function(output) {
            alert(output);
        },
        error: function(request, status, error){
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

and I have something like this in my passJobID.php

```
echo "
    <text style = 'font-size: 20px'><center><b>Qualifications</b></center></text>
    <label class = 'jdetails'>Age:</label>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>$min</text>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>-</text>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>$max</text>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>years old</text><br>
    <label class = 'jdetails'>Gender:</label>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>$gen</text><br>
    <label class = 'jdetails'>Height:</label>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>$ht</text>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>cm</text><br>
    <label class = 'jdetails'>Education:</label>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>$educ</text><br>
    <label class = 'jdetails'>Course:</label>
    <text class = 'jdetails'>$cour</text><br><br>
    <div class = 'col-lg-4' style = 'float: left'>
        <text class = 'jdetails'><center><b>Skills</b></center></text>
        <ul>    
            <li class = 'jdetails'>dfasdf</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = 'col-lg-4' style = 'float: left'>
        <text class = 'jdetails'><center><b>Requirements</b></center></text>
        <ul>    
            <li class = 'jdetails'>dfasdf</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class = 'col-lg-4' style = 'float: left'>
        <text class = 'jdetails'><center><b>Additional Qualifications</b></center></text>
        <ul>    
            <li class = 'jdetails'>dfasdf</li>
        </ul>
    </div>";
```

I wanted to print this block of echoed html code to my modal. I tried including passJobID.php in my modal but i got an error `undefined index 'vals'`

This is how the code opens the modal

```
    <button class='btn btn-default1 btn-sm jedit' data-toggle = 'modal' data-target = '#view' onclick = 'view($id, \"$name\")'>View Details</button>
```

And this is my modal code:

```
    <div id = "view" class = "modal fade" role = "dialog" onload = "view(document.getElementById('jid').value, document.getElementById('jtitle').value)">
                <div class = "modal-dialogjob">
                    <div class = "modal-contentjob">
                        <div class = "modal-header">                        
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">exit&nbsp;&times;</button>
                            <h3 class="modal-title" id = "jtitle"><center></center></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "modal-body">
                            <form style = "padding: 5px;">
                                <input type = "hidden" id = "jid">
                                <!--<?php
                                    include('passJobID.php');
                                ?>-->
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Seems like `idjob` is undefined

Comment: i don't think so, i tried to alert idjob's value inside view function and it's working properly. I have this function call "view(id, jname)"

Comment: which modal are you using?

Comment: how do you open that modal? (without inserting the html)

Comment: You'd have to open your modal 'manualy' - meaning not to use the bootstrap eventListeners - inside the succes-callback function, there you can pass along the html you recieved and modify the dom of that modal.